# How to have separate layout for (Posts and Page) and different for Homepage? CSS

Tags: css, wordpress

I am modifying my site using Custom CSS and whenever I make changes, it affects the whole site. I wanted to make only changes to the posts and pages and seperately for the homepage.

I asked my theme creator and this is what they replied.

"To know if you’re on homepage or a single page, check the classes on #content-wrapper-inside element. It will have ‘.home’ class on homepage, and ‘.single’ class on single post." I wasn't able to find.

I used these to customise,

```
@media (min-width:960px){
.main-content{
display: block;
padding-left:253px;
}

.sticky-kit-wrapper {
    margin-bottom: 120px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    max-width: 1480px;
}

.sticky-kit-wrapper {
    padding-left: 60px;
    padding-right: 0;
}
```

This affects the entire site, is there anyway I can code separately for my homepage?

My website is, www.defensionem.com

Thank-you for the help.

Comment: Based on information you provide `.home .sticky-kit-wrapper { ... }` will affects only homepage and `.single .sticky-kit-wrapper { ... }` will affects single page.

Comment: Hello. Let me try that. Thanks Vladimir!

Comment: I guess this web page is rendered by some CMS? Like Wordpress?

Comment: Yes, its Wordpress. @Hoshts Its a site for honoring military and things like that. Working on a new homepage.

Comment: Wordpress is by default putting the content type as a class on the body element. Sadly this might not be enough if you use a custom page as frontpage - then it will have both home and page as classes. All pages will have the class page and posts should have single.

Comment: So what do I do? @Hoshts

Comment: For the front and posts you follow Vladimir's example - prefix styles with .home or .single. For the pages I'm not completely sure myself. It's a bit more tricky if the front is a page. You can always inspect the pages with dev tools to find the classes. Look specifically in the body-tag.

Comment: You are kinda right. I tried, and when I use .home it affects all the pages and not the homepage alone. It doesn't affect the homepage though.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty easy, your theme is actually doing all the heavy lifting for you. All your pages in the site have the location built into the wrapper, so all you need to do is target the correct wrapper for the page eg:
Home : home
Archive : archive
Single : single
Page : page

So you css would look something like:

```
/* need to modify the home page */
.home .sticky-kit-wrapper { 
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: I posted the same answer and it was removed.